# Missing FMT Files & Directories

Tags: c++, gcc, fmt

When i attempt to compile some C++ code using the gcc compiler using the FMT library i get this error.

```
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find FMT: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find Colours: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::green), "This text is green.\n");
    fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::red) | fmt::emphasis::bold, "This text is bold and red.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed FMT.

Command to run:

```
cd "c:\Users\Surface Book 2\Documents\C++ Stuff\Colours\" ; if ($?) { g++ FMT Colours.cpp -o FMT Colours } ; if ($?) { .\FMT Colours }
```

Comment: How are you linking to the FMT library?

Comment: @Metactal, It looks like the linker (ld.exe) does not know where to find your FMT.dll and Colours.dll libraries. So, you may want to add `-LX:\folder\where\FMT\lives -LY:\folder\where\FMT\lives` to your build command:
`gcc -o fmt-test fmt-test.cpp -LX:\folder\where\FMT\lives -LY:\folder\where\FMT\lives -lFMT -lColours`. If you need more specific answers, you should update your question with the following details (1) The location to which FMT has been installed. (2) Your exact compilation command.

Comment: Remove the space from the filename. The code-runner extension you use seems to choke on those.

Comment: btw, I think you should include `fmt/format.h`, [`core.h`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/core.h) seems deprecated

Comment: In general fear the space. Too many tools choke over them even when properly delimited.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your paths contain spaces and therefore should be quoted, e.g.

```
g++ FMT Colours.cpp -o FMT Colours
```

changed to

```
g++ "FMT Colours.cpp" -o "FMT Colours"
```